# Variable will not update

Tags: python, python-2.7

Made my very first program for school using a basic calculator program but added a variable, not sure if it should be global or local. It calculates fine, but does not return 'tribble' as a new integer.

```
tribble = 1

def buy():
    x=int(raw_input("How many?"))
    return (tribble + x);

def sell():       
    x=int(raw_input("How many?"))
    return (tribble - x);

def breed():       
    x=int(raw_input("Multiply them by 2"))
    return (tribble * x);

def cull():        
    x=int(raw_input("Kill half your Tribbles"))
    return (tribble / x);

print "1: Buy"
print "2: Sell"
print "3: Breed"
print "4: Cull"
print "0: QUIT"

while True:

    CHOICE = int(raw_input("What will you do with your Tribbles?")) 

    if CHOICE == 1: 
        print "Buying Tribbles"
        print buy()
        print "You have" + str(tribble) + "Tribbles."

    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print sell()
        print 'Selling Tribbles'
        print "You have" + str(tribble) + "Tribbles."

    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print 'Breeding Tribbles, good luck.'
        print breed()
        print "You have" + str(tribble) + "Tribbles."

    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print "You're killing them!!"
        print cull()
        print "You have" + str(tribble) + "Tribbles."

    elif CHOICE == 0:
       exit()
```

Comment: You have both the python3 and python2 tags, but your code looks like python2.  This actually can affect the answer, so it is important to be specific about the version.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to update the value of tribble?

Then instead of print buy() you should update your variable by using: tribble = buy()

That way you know the value has been updated into the result from the function buy().

Do the same for other functions as well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You never reassign the result of your operation to the `tribble`. I also recommend that you avoid global variables where possible.  For example, I would rewrite your `cull` function to the following:

```
def cull(number_of_tribbles):
    x=int(raw_input("Kill half your Tribbles"))
    return number_of_tribbles / x  # No need for the parenthesis or the semicolon

# To use
tribble = cull(tribble)

# No need for explicit str conversion in print
print "You have", tribble, "Tribbles."
```

As a side note, it is odd that your message is "Kill half your Tribbles" yet you ask the user for input.  You should either hard code to `return tribbles / 2` or change the message to the user; same goes for `breed`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't update the value of *tribbles* in your functions and thus every time a function is called tribbles is being treated as 1, it's original value. Instead of returning tribbles * 2, for example, just do tribbles *= 2 and then return tribbles.

Comment: Watch out, this will result in an `UnboundLocalError` as you suggest it. Try it out yourself.

Comment: Sorry, you just have to put global before to tell python it's a global

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why update the `tribbles` global variable in place and also return from the function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes 'tribble' does not get updated inside the while loop. Because everytime the function returns updated tribble, you're just printing it.

You may want to update tribble this way:

```
    ...
    ...
    tribble= buy()
    print tribble
    ...
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
tribble = 1

def buy():
    global tribble
    x = int(raw_input("How many?"))
    tribble = tribble + x;

...

print "1: Buy"
print "2: Sell"
print "3: Breed"
print "4: Cull"

print "0: QUIT"

while True:

    CHOICE = int(raw_input("What will you do with your Tribbles?")) 

    if CHOICE == 1: 
        print "Buying Tribbles"
        print buy()            
        print "You have " + str(tribble) + " Tribbles."

    ...

    elif CHOICE == 0:
        exit()
```

All other methods should be changed in a similar way.

However, it's recommended to avoid using global variables.

Comment: Encouraging a novice programmer to use `global` will only create problems from them down the road.

Comment: @SethMMorton Good point. But this just to show one of the possible solutions. I will edit the answer.